# minimum and maximum of bilinear form

Tags: inequality, bilinear-form

I saw in an article the flowing inequality for vectors $ x,y\in R^n , Q \in R^{n \times n} $ :
$$ x^TQy\le {\frac 12}\lambda_{max}(Q){\Vert x \Vert}^2+{\frac 12}\lambda_{max}(Q){\Vert y \Vert}^2 $$
or some other version of it:

$$ x^TQy\le {\frac 1{2k^2}}\lambda_{max}(Q){\Vert x \Vert}^2+{\frac {k^2}2}\lambda_{max}(Q){\Vert y \Vert}^2 $$
I have two questions:

1. how can i prove the inequality?
2. is the a minimum version of it like:
   $$ {\frac 1{2k^2}}\lambda_{min}(Q){\Vert x \Vert}^2+{\frac {k^2}2}\lambda_{min}(Q){\Vert y \Vert}^2\le x^TQy $$
   or
   $$ {\frac 1{2}}\lambda_{min}(Q){\Vert x \Vert}^2+{\frac {1}2}\lambda_{min}(Q){\Vert y \Vert}^2\le x^TQy $$

Comment: Is $Q$ a positive semi-definite matrix?

Comment: 2. Note: If Q is postive definit, $y=0$ its impossible.

Comment: I think Q is symmetric.

Comment: Which article did the inequality come from? There is no reason, on a site such as this, to leave incomplete references.